# HTTP Post from ASP.NET to jsp

Tags: c#, jsp, httpwebrequest, http-post

I am trying to do a HTTP POST from ASP.NET and JSP and it is not working.

I have been reading articles on how to do a HTTP POST in C# and have come accross code snippets like the example I have written below using HttpWebRequest:

```
Stream stream = null;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RendercXMLForPosting(cXMLContent));
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Address"]);

webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("BuyerCoookie", punchOutSession.BuyerCookieID, "/", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"]));

try
{
    stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (stream != null)
        stream.Close();
}
```

When I try this no error is thrown but The 3rd party site is not recognising the POST, the 3rd Party site is a JSP site.

Is this the wrong way to post to a JSP site from ASP.NET?
Is there something I am missing?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT!!!**
I need to redirectthe user to the POSTing page after the post is complete, any help on that?

Comment: Are you well aware that the URL has to match the URL as specified in the `<form action>` of the JSP?

Comment: Nevermind then. The other side is apparently abusing a JSP instead of a servlet to control requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try flushing the request stream, and getting the response from the request, ie:

```
stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
stream.Flush
var rsp = webRequest.GetResponse();
using(var sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream())
    var result = sr.ReadToEnd(); // you might want to see what this is to debug
```

Comment: The code after `stream.Flush()` looks like is only needed when I want to check for a response. I guess this is not needed to perform the POST/

Comment: I would still suggest getting the response and reading it because the server might stop processing if it detects that the client connection has ended (which could happen if you don't get the response)